# Remove Key = NaN within loop for Specific Column

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements, nan, drop

I created a dictionary from a dataframe using a loop.

The key are ID's but some ID's are NaN from source.

How can I drop rows in the loop where the ID column (which is the key) equals to NaN?

Answer (score 1):

You can drop NaN rows from the dataframe before turning it into a dictionary like this:

```
df = df[df['ID'].notna()]
```

and then proceede as before in creating your dictionary.